# iPhone: NSMutableDictionary key

Tags: iphone

I was trying to use a CLLocation object as a key for a dictionary... but it doesnt seem to work.  Works well if I use a string.  Is this not possible?

```
[dict setObject:tmp forKey:tmpLocation]; // objectForKey always returns null on same location
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up passing a string lat/long combo which served my purpose.